# Lie algebra valued potential vector

Tags: potential, gauge-theory, lie-algebra, yang-mills

Maybe it is a simple question but I have some difficulty to understand the explicit matrix form of this usual relation:

$$A_\mu=A^a_\mu \tau_a$$

where $A^a_\mu $ is the Lie  algebra valued potential vector and  $\tau_a$ the generators of $SU(2)$.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, $\tau_a$'s are Pauli matrices, i.e.,
$$
\tau_1=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{array}
\right),\quad\tau_2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0&-i\\
i&0
\end{array}
\right),\quad\tau_3=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&-1
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
A_{\mu}=A_{\mu}^a\tau_a&=A_{\mu}^1\tau_1+A_{\mu}^2\tau_2+A_{\mu}^3\tau_3\\
&=A_{\mu}^1\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{array}
\right)+A_{\mu}^2\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0&-i\\
i&0
\end{array}
\right)+A_{\mu}^3\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&-1
\end{array}
\right),
\end{align}
where $A_{\mu}^a$'s are scalar-valued functions.

Comment: More explicitly $A_\mu =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
A^3_\mu & A^1_\mu -i A^2_\mu \\
 A^1_\mu +i A^2_\mu & -A^3_\mu
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: But, how can you cope with the fact that on the left side you have a 4-vector and on the right side you have a 2x2 matrix? Thank you for your help in advanced.

Comment: @Oscar: That's fully tensorial. For this $A_{\mu}$ part, it deals with two spinors $\left(\psi_1,\psi_2\right)$, each component of which is a Dirac spinor.

Comment: @Oscar: More precisely, you may put it as$$i\left[\gamma_a^b\right]^{\mu}\left(\partial_{\mu}+ie\left[A_c^d\right]_{\mu}\right)\left[\psi_d^a\right]=m\left[\psi_c^b\right],$$where the indices $a,b,c,d$ indicate the matrix rows and columns (respective matrices are highlighted in the brackets). You could see that in the isospin case, $\psi$ has eight components rather than four, because it contains two Dirac spinors.